# Magento 2 customer login not working on my centos 7 server but works in test server

Tags: magento2, customer, login

Magento 2 login is not working as expected on my centos 7 server. If i enter wrong credentials into the login form and hit submit, the page refreshes and the following happens:
1. No error message is returned
2. The form clears off the inputted login credentials.
3. Customer is not logged in even if the credentials are correct.

I went further to install a fresh Magento 2.2.6 on the same server. I tried to login as a customer, even though I did not register. I expected to get an error feedback but I got the same result as above.

Please note that admin backend login is working fine.

**Things I have done**
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean`

I have also made the following folders writable: generated, var/*, pub/static

I need your help as I have been on this for 3 days. Thanks in anticipation.

**Issue has been resolved**
I noticed a timezone difference between the database server and application server. I sync the two and it worked.

Comment: Assuming you have deleted the cache before trying the above steps , for me it sounds like its a cookies or session issue , try to delete the session folder and try again (only on development server , not production) , and make sure the cookies settings in Magento admin is set correctly .

Comment: The cookie settings in Magento admin has the default values. I have deleted the session folder but still not working.

Comment: Would you provide the cookies values ? also have you checked if there is any disk space issue (it happened to me once because there were no enough space on the disk)

Comment: Also , does the problem exist on every browser ?

Comment: I added `'session' => [
    'save' => 'files',
    'save_path' => '/var/www/html/var/session',
  ]`. With this, customer login started working in firefox but not in chrome. Also error messages are not being returned in both occasions.

Comment: Chrome has problem with localhost , try to replace the path localhost with 127.0.0.1 instead , then try again.

Comment: I am not using localhost. I have a domain name

Answer (score 0):

Please check your cookie options. From the database:

```
select * from core_config_data where path = "web/cookie/cookie_domain";
```

Check you have your current domain, if not change it and clear cache.

Comment: I have set the cookie_domain but its still not working.